# Change default find method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I've read this somewhere but I can't find it now.

I'm trying to change the default "find" method on a model from the id to for example the name. So when I map resources to a model it uses the the name instead of the id.

I don't remember if this was a parameter in the resources command in the route file or if it was something you added to the model? I think it was the latter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking of overriding the `to_param` method within the model so that a field other than the ID is used within URLs. [This Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url) shows you how.

- [to_param API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001840)

Comment: i think he want User.find('salil') should return the user with name 'salil' instead of searching for id with 'salil'

Comment: Yeah, now I remember I didn't read it, I saw it in a Railscast ;) Thanks!